# windows cmd, пытаюсь копировать папку

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Есть клон репозитория (D:\Work), в нем проект. Пишу .bat который выполняет определенные действия с файлами и затем запускает проект. Первое, что он должен сделать, это скопировать папку из одного места в другое.

пишу:

```
copy /Y D:\Work\PRJ\version3\POST D:\Work\PRJ\POST
```

Получаю:

```
Copy-Item : Не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент "D:\Work\PRJ\POST".
строка:1 знак:1
+ copy /Y "D:\Work\PRJ\version3\POST" "D:\Work\PRJ\P...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Можете через PowerShell

```
Copy-Item -Path "D:\Work\PRJ\version3\POST" -Destination "D:\Work\PRJ\POST" -Recurse -Force
```

Ну `.bat` поменять на `.ps1`

Надеюсь помог.